# Modal view controller within split view controller - too short

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a standard `UISplitViewController` with a master and detail view controller. I am attempting to present a modal view controller in the master pane (i.e. left-hand side), similar to when you tap the "Groups" button in the Contacts.app on an iPad.

The modal view controller is hooked-up via a segue in the storyboard, with the "presentation" property set to "Current Context" so that it displays within the master pane.

However, whenever it appears, it is too short:

[image]

...leaving a fairly sizable gap at the bottom of the master pane (circled below). This does not occur on the actual master view itself, only on the modally presented view controller.

In the storyboard, the size of the modal view controller is set to "Master" to emulate the size of display on screen. If I set this to "Inferred" the problem goes away, but it makes the view controller extremely wide and basically occupies the entire screen (albeit hidden behind the detail view controller) but results in the accessory view not being visible. A bit strange since those are just suppose to be "simulated metrics" in the storyboard!

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it is giving the height of master view in landscape mode. You are using in portrait mode. Check if the height is around 703 then it is giving height in landscape mode.

Comment: The height of the view is 852 which is bigger than landscape but smaller than portrait (go figure...). The simulated metrics of the view controller in the storyboard are set as "Master" and "Portrait".